# MySQL Error 1064 on Stored Procedure Definition

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am new to MySQL procedures. I am simply trying to run a cursor over a data set and for each row run a different procedure (one I happen to know works). I am getting error code 1064 on line three of the below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `safecycle`.`sp_aggregateAllPORDaily` ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE porID SMALLINT UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM point_of_recycle;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO porID;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    CALL sp_aggregatePORDaily(porID);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

I have been banging my head against the wall for a while and would very much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't changed your delimiter, so the first `;` encountered terminates the entire statement.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE
    blah blah blah
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

By changing the delimiter this way, you can safely define your multi-statement procedure, embedding the normal `;` within it, and then end the create statement with the 'new' delimiter. Afterwards, you restore the standard delimiter and go on as usual.

Comment: Very weird of sqlyog to generate Delimiter with ';' in the starting, which was actually terminating the entire statement perhaps, when run from command line.